Prometheus unable to scrap Traefik
I have Traefik deployed with following config
  traefik.toml: |
    ## static configuration
    [global]
      checkNewVersion = true

    [entryPoints]
      [entryPoints.web]
        address = ":80"
      [entryPoints.websecure]
        address = ":443"

    [providers]
      [providers.kubernetesCRD]
      [providers.file]
        directory = "/etc/traefik/providers/"
        watch = true
      [providers.kubernetesIngress]
        ingressClass = "traefik-cert-manager"

    [log]
      level = "INFO"

    [accessLog]

    [api]
      insecure = true
      dashboard = true
      debug = true

    [metrics]
      [metrics.prometheus]
        buckets = [0.1,0.3,1.2,5.0]
        addEntryPointsLabels = true
        addServicesLabels = true


and Deployment Manifest

kind: DaemonSet
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: traefik
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    app: traefik
  annotations:
     prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
     prometheus.io/port: "8080"
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: traefik
  minReadySeconds: 5
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: traefik
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: traefik-ingress-controller
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      hostNetwork: true
      containers:
      - name: traefik
        image: traefik:2.9.6
        ports:
          - name: web
            containerPort: 80
          - name: websecure
            containerPort: 443
          - name: internal
            containerPort: 4080
          - name: internalsecure
            containerPort: 4043
          - name: admin
            containerPort: 8080
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 1
          httpGet:
            path: /ping
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 2
        livenessProbe: 
          httpGet: 
            path: /ping 
            port: 8080 
          failureThreshold: 5 
          initialDelaySeconds: 10 
          periodSeconds: 10 
          successThreshold: 1 
          timeoutSeconds: 2 
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        env:
          - name: AWS_REGION
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: aws-config
                key: aws_region
          - name: AWS_HOSTED_ZONE_ID
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: aws-config
                key: aws_hosted_zone_id
          - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: aws-secret
                key: access_key
          - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: aws-secret
                key: secret_key
        volumeMounts:
          - name: traefik-config
            mountPath: /etc/traefik/traefik.toml
            subPath: traefik.toml
          - name: traefik-config
            mountPath: /etc/traefik/providers/dynamic.toml
            subPath: dynamic.toml
          - name: traefik-storage
            mountPath: /etc/traefik/storage/
      volumes:
      - name: traefik-config
        configMap:
          name: traefik-conf
      - name: traefik-storage
        hostPath:
          path: /tmp/traefik
          type: DirectoryOrCreate

With this I can see metrics at /metrics for Traefik.
But unable to get it into Prometheus with following scrap job
      - job_name: 'traefik'
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
          - role: pod
        relabel_configs:
          - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_app]
            action: keep
            regex: traefik
          - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
            action: keep
            regex: true
          - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
            action: replace
            target_label: __metrics_path__
            regex: (.+)
          - source_labels: [__address__]
            action: replace
            target_label: __address__
            regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
            replacement: $1:9100

Prometheus pod is running with following config
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 2000
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 1000

What I am missing here ?

Is your prometheus configuration working for other pods? Are you seeing any obvious errors? Is prometheus deployed in the same namespace as traefik? What service account is prometheus using, and does that sa have the necessary permissions to inspect pods?

Yes other scrape jobs are working. Don't see any obvious error in prometheus. prometheus & traefik is running in different namespace.
